# cannot render json without login. What should i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am new to rails and i am trying few examples. I have login page using devise authentication and i have one more page where user can store their details, view, edit and delete the details. It is displayed in html format, once login is done. I want to produce json for iPhone so if i call as localhost:3000/posts/1.json it does not show json but after login i can see the json. so how shoud i do this? Pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the few you said, add this to your `PostsController`:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]
```

But be aware that this action is now available to anyone, even the html version.

Consider creating another dedicated action if it isn't safe in your context.

Comment: I will tell you the needs clearly. I have to make a login page and i have to make a seperate page for each user where they can store their details.And also i have to provide an api for iphone app, so i need to provide the data as json. Somehow i managed to do authentication with devise example in github and then used the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html site and created the page for storing user details and what i did is i have used "if session[:user_id]" before everything in the controller to check for the user and only then it will display. So what should i do?

Comment: if you use devise, you should just hacve a before_filter named `authenticate_user!` see their official doc